# How to filter the data sent to a Shopify webhook?

Tags: shopify

While creating a webhook for Shopify 'Order creation' event, how can I filter the data that is sent in the POST request JSON? It tends to send all the data by default, which includes lots of customer information which I don't want to share with the webhook. I couldn't find any option in the Admin dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shopify just sends the whole order. If you want to limit that you could write your own webhook receiver and then filter and re-post the filtered data.

Some really low cost infrastructure for that would be an AWS Lambda function.

Rewind has a nice post showing the [AWS setup needed for that](https://rewind.io/blog/handle-shopify-webhooks-without-a-server/) which posts the webhooks to a queue to serialize downstream processing and handle spikes. You should be able to leverage their example to filter and there are tons of examples of how to post the filtered data on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Shopify webhooks are HTTPS. That means the payload is encrypted from prying eyes. Secondly, the webhook endpoint you create can inspect that security as Shopify includes authentication tokens.

So whether a webhook contains data you want or do not want, there is no sharing of that information with anyone. It is up to you to not share once you receive it. But that has zero to do with Shopify or the webhooks.